# Clojure dictionary of words

Tags: clojure

I want a dictionary of English words available, to pick random english words.  I have a dictionary text file that I downloaded form the internet which has almost 1 million words, what's the best way to go about using this list in Clojure, given that most of the time I'll only need 1 randomly selected word?

Edit:

To answer the comments, this is for some tests which I may turn into load tests which is why I want a decent number of random words and I guess access speed is the most important thing.  I do not want to use a database for this.  I originally thought of a dictionary just because that's the first thing that popped into my mind but I think a random sequence of letters and numbers would be good enough, perhaps I will just use a UUID as a string.

Comment: Stuff it in a database with an ordinal index and pick a random number?

Comment: What do you mean by most of the time? Does your program run once, picks a word and does what it needs with it, or does it run in a loop (i.e. hangman)? Do you really need 1M words, or would it be best to use relatively popular ones only?

Comment: Define "best". "Best" in terms of memory consumption? "Best" in terms of lookup speed? "Best" in terms of speed/clarity of implementation?

Comment: See how slow it is to get a random word in Clojure, and if it is prohibitively slow for your purposes, shove it in postgres and query on it, I guess. It's hard to suggest options without really knowing what you're doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read all the words into a Vector and then call [rand-nth](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/rand-nth) , e.g.

```
(rand-nth all-words)
```

rand-nth uses the nth function on the underlying data structure and Clojure Vectors have log32N performance for index based retrieval.

Edit: This is assuming that it is for a test environment as you described in your question. A more memory efficient method would be to use [RandomAccessFile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html) and seek to a random location in the file of words, read until you find the first word delimiter (e.g. comma, EOL) and then read the following bytes until the next delimiter which will give you a random word.